# conditional formatting with date not working properly. SPD2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, conditional

I created a conditional formatting on a column with date ('Due date') and it worked fine until yesterday.
This morning I noticed its not working anymore. I open SPD2010 and remove the condition and recreate it. In short I want the Font to change if due date is passed.

It works partially on SPD2010 (3 feb should also be in red. Today is 1 March)

[image]

However on Internet explorer only date from 2016 are formatted but non from 2017 even if the date has passed.

[image]

Any idea what can cause this?

Comment: Hi,
SPD2010 condition in advance mode show the following code: ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string($thisNode/@Due_x0020_date))) <= ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string($Today))) . Is there any reason why it will not work?
I also found this syntax using the advance mode: ddwrt:Today(). Is there any way to use this expression instead of (string($Today))?

Answer (score 0):

For this scenario you better use CSR to format the labels
here is the code sample on how to apply conditional formating on list view items.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-0a786cdd

Comment: Hello Suresh. Thank you for the reply. unfortunately this isnot helpful for me. First the you mention SP2013 while on my company we use 2010. 2nd I am not a programmer hence upload Java script,  OOTB, LIST schema PowerShell are not terms that tell me anything and unless there is a full step by step explanation I doubt I can use it. And most important thing the solution I used with conditional formatting in SPD2010 was working until yesterday and now no, I hope there is a way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday was another month...

So if something worked yesterday and not today.....

I suspect a configuration mistake on your behalf

Comment: Hi. I only used the SPD2010 GUI interface to add the condition. checking the code behind it (by clicking advance on the GUI window of conditional formatting on SPD2010):
ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string($thisNode/@Due_x0020_date))) < ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string($Today)))
It is clearly mention $Today.
I will wait for tmorrow see if really something in changing month (Feb is always tricky since it is not fixed) however since it only works on item from 2016 and not 2017 is the month really matter here?
Which configuration I could have set incorrectly?

Comment: Sorry, .. it was tough.. but I managed to kick the XSLT habit.. So I can't help you here